# getting TextBox Value in ClientHandler google apps script

Tags: event-handling, google-apps-script, client-side-scripting

What I would like to do is the following:

```
var handler1 app.createClientHandler().
              forTargets(textbox2).setText(textbox1.getText());
```

However .getText doesn't exist on the client side.

I can get it to work using ServerHandler and e.parameter.textbox1:

```
v3.setText(e.parameter.textbox1);
```

Are there other solutions or workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible to read the values of widgets in a client handler.